# how to display a string along with quotations

Tags: javascript, string

```
var str="hello";
console.log(str.length);
var str1=""
for(i=str.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
    str1 = str1 + str[i];
}

console.log(str1);
```

The output of this code is olleh .
but i need the output to be **"olleh"**. How to get that output?

Answer (score 4):

You can concat the final result with `"`

```
var conString = '"'+str1+'"'
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/dyfsx02o/)

Comment: Thank you. i got the output that i needed .

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
var str = `"hello"`;
console.log(str.length);
var str1 = "";
for(i = str.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {
    str1 = str1 + str[i];
}

console.log(str1);
```

Comment: hmm that might require es6 transpiling though, especially for IE

Comment: @derp Returns expected result at chromium 50, firefox 47; not certain about ie

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotation marks to wrap your double quotation marks

```
var str="hello";
console.log(str.length);
var str1=""
for(i=str.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
    str1 = str1 + str[i];
}

console.log('"'+str1+'"');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use quotes with back slashes. it will count as quotes. first quotes are used to define a string.

```js
var str="\"hello\"";
console.log(str.length);
var str1=""
for(i=str.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
    str1 = str1 + str[i];
}

document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML=str1;
```

```html
<div id="hello"></div>
```

Comment: Or use single quotes, so that escaping isn't needed. `'"hello"'`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var str="hello";
    console.log(str.length);
    var str1=""
    for(i=str.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
        str1 = str1 + str[i];
    }
    console.log('"'+str1+'"');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use format specifier and put quotes around it.

```
var str="hello";
console.log(str.length);
var str1=""
for(i=str.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
    str1 = str1 + str[i];
}
console.log('"%s"',str1);
```

*Or*

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(str1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var str="hello";
str=str.concat("\"");
//console.log(str.length);
var str1=""
for(i=str.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
    str1 = str1 + str[i];
}
str1=str1.concat("\"");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=str1;
console.log('"%s"',str1);


}
</script>

</body>

</html>
```